# Getting a name, with fallback behavior

Tags: ruby

Is there a cleaner way to write:

```
def b_fname
    if mdes_version_is_after?(3.0)
      result = c_fname
    else
      result = response_for("#{birth_baby_name_prefix}.BABY_FNAME")
    end
    if result.empty?
      result = 'your baby'
    end
  result
end
```

Comment: To explain the downvote: could please add more information about the purpose of your code?

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- In Ruby `if` conditionals can be used also as expressions, not only statements.
- Don't change/rebind the value of existing variables, create a new one ([FP in Ruby](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming)).

I'd write:

```
def b_fname
  name = if mdes_version_is_after?(3.0)
    c_fname
  else
    response_for("#{birth_baby_name_prefix}.BABY_FNAME")
  end
  name.empty? ? 'your baby' : name
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd also consider changing some variable/function names. `b_fname`, `mdes`, and `c_fname` are not super descriptive. It's a few extra keystrokes, but the readability is well worth it, IMO.

Comment: Although I agree with your sentiment, those names are prescribed from the an outside source, we have no control over those particular names.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Carry on, then!

Answer (score 1):

The following version uses the ternary operator, which avoids one assignment:

```
def b_fname
  if mdes_version_is_after?(3.0)
    result = c_fname
  else
    result = response_for("#{birth_baby_name_prefix}.BABY_FNAME")
  end

  result.empty? ? 'your baby' : result
end
```

You can also do the following if you don't like the ternary operator:

```
def b_fname
  if mdes_version_is_after?(3.0)
    result = c_fname
  else
    result = response_for("#{birth_baby_name_prefix}.BABY_FNAME")
  end

  if result.empty?
    'your baby'
  else
    result
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I would probably do away with the variable named result, this would be a clean way to do this.  In other words, regarding the variable assignment, don't conditionally assign a variable through all conditional paths.  Just assign it the result of the condition one time.

```
def b_fname
  result = if mdes_version_is_after?(3.0)
             c_fname
           else
             response_for("#{birth_baby_name_prefix}.BABY_FNAME")
           end
 result or 'your baby'
end
```

I think I might prefer this version though, in some ways

```
def b_fname
  if mdes_version_is_after?(3.0)
    c_fname
  else
    response_for("#{birth_baby_name_prefix}.BABY_FNAME")
  end || 'your baby'
end
```

But without an `if..else`

```
def b_fname
  mdes_version_is_after?(3.0) && c_fname ||
    response_for("#{birth_baby_name_prefix}.BABY_FNAME") ||
    'your baby'
end
```